# How do I fix "Failed to look for applications online" error when looking for a new default program online?

Tags: 13.04

I get the following error:

```
Failed to look for applications online

GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.xdg.Exceptions.ParsingError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 1030, in _install_mime_types
    path))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.parse(filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 42, in parse
    IniFile.parse(self, file, ["Desktop Entry", "KDE Desktop Entry"])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/IniFile.py", line 81, in parse
    raise ParsingError("Invalid line: " + line, filename)
    ParsingError: ParsingError in file '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop', Invalid line: - RSI (Repetitive Strain Injury) oraz wspomaga rekonwalescencj\u0119"
```

Any ideas?

This happens when I right click a program, open with, other application..., find applications on-line. then this error pops up.

Comment: What exact command did you run? Please add it to your question. Thanks.

Comment: duplicates? http://askubuntu.com/questions/308301/why-this-error-generate-when-i-check-online-update-or-other

Comment: You should report this as a bug. Use ubuntu-bug from command line after the error happens

Answer (score 0):

remove `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop` should solve the problem, for me it solved ;)

```
sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop
```

Source from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1190097